# Reduce MutiView page size? (not page number)

Tags: asp.net

In my mutiview I have few view, each view contains some user control.

In one of my user control(inside one of the page view) which is not the selected active view.  The user control loads few hundreds of items a combobox that inside the user control...

That user control made the page size increased like 500kbs...

I wonder is there good idea to reduce the page size? Because now every page is 500kbs...

In the begining I thought the page size for inactive page doesn't affect active page because its hidden....

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Try loading the combo box items dynammically. Here is the link how you can do it:

http://forums.asp.net/p/1453076/3322353.aspx

Hope it helps!